# Should I do away with the HVAC zone system entirely or spend the money to replace/update a non working system?

Tags: hvac, zoned-heating

I know nothing about this but I have a two story 2000 sq. ft home built in 2006. The zone system failed. To update it will cost alot. To do away with the two zone system is much less. I'm not sure how important it is to replace the multi zoned system.

Comment: We're gonna  need a lot more info to help give decent advice. What type of heating/cooling system? How many zones? How are they controlled. What "failed" and why? Also, how many estimates did you get? Sometimes HVAC companies aren't completely honest about the options.

Comment: Have to agree with George, what kind of zone system? Multiple heat / cooling units controlled by factory boards or thermostat? Ducted control?

Comment: Have you had a trustworthy and knowledgeable contractor run a Manual J, Eighth Edition *load calculation* on your house? You may be shocked by the results, especially on a 2006 house...